FullCalendar not updating view despite changing initialView state
I'm using FullCalendar in my React application and trying to change the initial view based on a state variable (isCheckoutVisible). I've noticed that even though I update the initialView state, FullCalendar does not update the view as expected. It seems like FullCalendar is remembering the initial value and not allowing it to be overwritten.
Here's a simplified version of my code
// Inside my functional component
const [initialView, setInitialView] = useState('timeGridWeek');

useEffect(() => {
  setInitialView(isCheckoutVisible ? 'listMonth' : window.innerWidth > 768 ? 'timeGridWeek' : 'timeGridDay');
}, [isCheckoutVisible]);

return (
  <FullCalendar
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
    initialView={initialView}
    // other props...
  />
);

I've tried updating the initialView state and passing it to FullCalendar, but it doesn't reflect the changes in the calendar view. Is there a way to force FullCalendar to update its view when the initialView state changes?


It seems like FullCalendar is remembering the initial value and not
allowing it to be overwritten

...correct. That's why it's called an "initial" view - the clue's in the name :-). It only applies when the calendar is initially loaded.
If you want a "subsequent" view - i.e. you want to change to another view after the calendar has first loaded then - as documented - you can use fullCalendar's  changeView method.
Example:
calendar.changeView('timeGridDay');

